# Virtualbox CPU limit lower than actual number of CPUs available on system

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

## Problem

I am trying to set up a virtual insatnce of ubuntu on my windows PC. I want to allocate 14/16 CPUs to the virtual machine. However I get the following error message in Virtualbox:

[image: Allocated more CPUs than are available on system]

It warns me that doing this may harm my performance.

However in my virtualbox it sais I have access to all 14 CPUs:

[image: The CPUs expected]

## Question(s)

1. Why do I get the warning: 'You only have 8 CPUs' when in fact I have 16?
   and,
2. Am I actually harming my virtual machines performance by going over this 8 CPU treshold?

## Specs

OS: Windows 11

Virtualbox running ubuntu 22.04

[image: dxdiag image of specs]

Comment: Setting more than your actual hardware core count is counter-productive. Ignore any HT cores. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/212279/intel-core-i711700-processor-16m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: @Tetsujin So this means the Virtual machine can't make use of HT?

Comment: A VM once running doesn't really know the difference [it cannot really tell what it's running on] so the 'virtualiser' has to tell you before you make a mistake. The 'best' use is to set the number of physical cores. That lets the machine breathe with ideal thread allocation.

Comment: Understood. Performance-wise, does this mean it is better for me to install Ubuntu on my PC?

Comment: It's always faster to run natively, but you lose the ability to work in both at once. 'Better' is your call to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get the warning: 'You only have 8 CPUs' when in fact I have 16?

You have 1 CPU that has 8 physical cores. Each of them is exposed as 2 logical cores due to HyperThreading. 8 × 2 = 16.

VirtualBox warns you that assigning more cores than the number of physical cores present in your system will actually make the performance worse.

> Am I actually harming my virtual machines performance by going over this 8 CPU treshold?

Check for yourself! Set up a benchmark that realistically models your workload and test both configurations.